# There is no email notification link in the Stack Exchange menu 

Tags: support, email-notification

I followed the instructions [on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/) to try to set up email notification. But there is no link there at the bottom-left corner of the Stack Exchange logo.

[image]

I tried in FF and IE. But now suddenly I can see email link in FF. Not sure what changed

Comment: Please specify which site you see this on and which browser you're using

Comment: It appears ying is doing this from [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That's the problem! It doesn't show for me on stackexchange.com but it shows on all other pages.

Comment: +1 @All: Yes, doesn't show for me either in FF.

Comment: so the hint is click "stackexchange" but not actually going there.